# How do I add a New Contact button (with reference to Account) from a VisualForce page

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller

I have a VS page embedded in the standard Account page, using Tabs/pageBlockTables to separate Active Contacts from Inactive Contacts.  Now I need a 'New Contact' button to navigate to the standard New Contact page, and to auto-relate the new Contact to the Account. It also should return the user to the Account page that called 'New Contact'.  I am new to Apex/VisualForce and I can't get anything I've found so far to work.

Comment: You should provide the code you have so far and where specifically you are stuck

Comment: My VS page looks like this.  the button opens a new contact page, but the Account Id is not filled in/related.                                                         <apex:tabPanel switchType="Ajax">
         <apex:tab label="Active Contacts" name="ActiveContacts">
     <apex:pageBlock title="Contacts">  
         <apex:commandButton value="New Contact" action="{!URLFOR($Action.Contact.NewContact)}" />   
             <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!ActiveContacts}" var="a">
                  <apex:column headervalue="View"><apex:outputLink value="/{!a.id}">

Comment: @GaryFitz You can edit your question at any time. So better to update the question with all required details rather than putting in comments whenever possible.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution :

Make your `New Contact` button(or link) call this action :

```
<apex:pageBlockButtons location="top">
    <apex:commandLink value="New Contact" action="{!newContact}" styleClass="btn"/>
</apex:pageBlockButtons>
```

and then in  `newContact` Action put this code :

```
public PageReference newContact(){
    PageReference pg = new PageReference('/003/e');

    pg.getParameters().put('saveURL', '/'+ currentAccount.Id);
    pg.getParameters().put('cancelURL', '/'+ currentAccount.Id);
    pg.getParameters().put('accid', currentAccount.Id);

    return pg;

}
```

the `currentAccount` class variable you should instantiate it in your class Constructor :

```
currentAccount = [select Id, Name from Account where Id = :<yourAccountId>];
```

Comment: you're welcome, can you please mark the answer as the best one